# Open Sharepoint Excel Files With VBA

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

I'm using VBA in Excel to loop through files on a sharepoint site and open all Excel files.

The code crashes Excel the first time I run it, however, if I then reopen it it works fine.

Are there any known issues around this?

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code:

```
Sub Refresh()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim fso As FileSystemObject
        Dim fldr As Folder
        Dim f As File
        Dim wb As Workbook

        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(SharePointSite)

        For Each f In fldr.Files

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(SharePointURL & f.Name)

        Next f

        Set wb = Nothing
        Set fldr = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing

        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Does it crash with an error? If so - what kind of error?
2. Could you post your code please? Have you put any defence coding?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

No error comes up, Excel just crashes.

I've put the code in the original post.

Cheers.

Comment: oh, could you let us know versions of Excel and SharePoint? I believe there were some issues with compability between Excel 2003 and latest version of SharePoint.

Comment: Excel 2010 and Sharepoint 2003.

Comment: And I currently have no defence coding.

Comment: I tested your code in our environment and it worked fine (Excel 2010 ver.14.0.6023.1000, SharePoint 2010 ver. 12.0.0.6557). I am afraid that's everything what I can do for you :(

Comment: Thanks anyway, appreciate your time.

Looks like I'll just be closing and reopening it each time!

Comment: What are the values of SharePointSite and SharePointURL ? Is one a UNC (\\blahblah\...) and the other a http ?

Comment: Hi Tim,

`SharePointSite = "\\intranet.blahblah"`

`SharePointURL = "http://intranet.blahblah"`

Any idea what's causing the crashing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried mapping sharepoint to a drive letter and using that reference instead of the URL?

Comment: Just tried this and it solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: 2 general points: 1) **NEVER** set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` until your code is working - it just makes your life more difficult. 2) If @AlistairWeir provided your answer, it would be great if he would write it as such, and you could accept it - makes it easier for someone else to find it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mapping the document library to a drive letter try using the WebDAV address to access the library in your code. This way if the macro is distributed no one will be dependent upon having the "Z:" drive being mapped to a specific location

Set your FilePath variable equal to a string like this (use @SSL for HTTPS sites):

`\\sharepoint.site.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\site1\usersite\Book2\Shared%20Documents`

If you are going to access the text file directly then set it up like this:

`\\sharepoint.site.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\site1\usersite\Book2\Shared%20Documents
\Test_Text1.txt`

Take a look at [this blog post](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/unc-path-naming-for-files-stored-on-sharepoint-2/) for a full explanation on retrieving the WebDAV path.